# How to check if chrome.runtime.lastError was checked?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

When `chrome.storage.sync.set` fails, it calls it's callback and sets `chrome.runtime.lastError` and unless I access that variable I get

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running storage.set: QUOTA_BYTES_PER_ITEM quota exceeded
```

in console. Cool, from what I googled that's expected. However, I'm writing a library and don't want user to bother with this, so I have the callback wrapped in another function. But I don't know how to check if `chrome.runtime.lastError` was checked yet or not in order to know if I want to supress my handling or not.

I want to have something like

```
chrome.storage.sync.set(key: "foo" * 1024 * 1024, function () {
    user_callback();
    if (!was_last_error_checked()) {
        user_error_callback(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
    }
});
```

however, I have no idea how to implement `was_last_error_checked`...

EDIT: to make it clearer: is there a way to check if `chrome.runtime.lastError` was accessed inside `user_callback` so I can avoid triggering `user_error_callback` with assumption that `user_callback` already handled the error?

Comment: if (chrome.runtime.lastError) { console.error('derp') } else { /* do something */ }

Comment: maybe I said poorly what my problem is... I need to now if the variable was already checked inside `user_callback` in order not to trigger the `user_error_callback` assuming `user_callback` already handled the error

Comment: You can switch to promises instead and just reject on error.

Comment: welp, I guess this was XY problem.. I can just fail the promise instead of raising exception.. will probably work :)

Comment: You can also try spoofing `chrome.runtime` with a `Proxy` (where you can detect `lastError` being accessed) before invoking the user callback, then restore the previous chrome.runtime. Or you can try using Object.defineProperty to spoof just `lastError` on chrome.runtime.

Comment: The proxy way is awesome :) seems to work just fine. Could you write it as an answer so I can accept that?

Comment: I think it'd be better if you post an answer with the actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments there seem to be two way to handle my issue:

1) Just fail a promise when `lastError` is defined:

```
def set(**data)
  promise = Promise.new
  %x{
    #{@wrap}.set(data.$to_n(), function() {
      if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        promise.$reject(chrome.runtime.lastError.message)
      } else {
        promise.$resolve();
      }
    });
  }
  promise
end
```

2) Use `Proxy` object to replace `chrome.runtime` and detect access to `lastError`:

```
%x{
  var handler = {
    get: function(obj, prop) {
      window.last_error_accessed = true;
      return obj[prop];
    }
  };
  chrome.runtime = new Proxy(chrome.runtime, handler);
}
```

and in callback:

```
def set(**data)
  promise = Promise.new
  %x{
    #{@wrap}.set(data.$to_n(), function() {
      window.last_error_accessed = false;
      promise.$resolve();
      if (!window.last_error_accessed && chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        Opal.Kernel.$raise(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
      }
    });
  }
  promise
end
```